# IOS app without launch image?

Tags: iphone, ios, launch

I just don't want to allocate 2-4 different sized images in bundle. They will shown for 0.2 second at launch and later never be used. Thus. I removed all launch images (just useless)

Is it acceptable by apple IOS app publishing rules ?
(I cant see launch image. application starts immediately.thus launch image cannot be seen)

Comment: I think launch images are very useful option(if we exclude apple's requirement for a moment)to get users attention to your app. Also, think if your app taking some time to launch and you don't have launch images to display, a black screen will put up, that will surely look odd and may be user get wrong impression that app get crashed.

Comment: option ?It seems it is not an option.it seems a compulsion.
application starts really fast.thus it takes 0.2 seconds to show launch image.if user is not a bee; cannot see this launch image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes dear, 
It is neccesarry.

Your app must include at least one image to be displayed while your app is launching.

See here [App-Related Resources - iOS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Comment: If I make my launch screen "almost identical to the first screen" users will just poke at the button and never get a response. I don't understand the purpose of the launch screen other than to make users angry.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, The app will not be acceptable  without any launch images.

Answer (score 1):

Quote by Apple:

> Custom icons and images:
>   - Application icon (required for all apps)
>   - App icon for the App Store (required for all apps)
>   - Launch image (required for all apps)
>   - [...]

The app will indeed be rejected when no launch image is specified.
But you can take a screenshot of your root view and setup it like launch image.

Answer (score 1):

Ramos, there is compulsion of launch images. I did not added the launch images in my project and my app is on appstore. So you can submit app without adding launch images.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for this answer.I will post to review without launch images. Some of rules are really useless.I dont believe device detects if application is for iphone5 by checking a new brand new 568h@2x image.I tested on all devices (iphone4s iphone5 + Ipad family) and didn't see any problem without launch images. I ll post app to review Just want to see what happens.

Comment: N. Ramos Yes please proceed and see what happened. I Hope everything will go as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a view after some delay so that launch image should stay on screen for a while. I guess this is a workaround for this issue.

Edited:

In viewWillAppear

```
[self performSelector:@selector(viewDidLoad) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0];
```

Comment: is it possible to make hang on launch image for some 1-2 seconds ?
because my app starts fast and really launch image is not shown.(0.1-0.2 sec). but as I understand your method (showing a view after some delay), if I reload image doesnt it take a screen flickering issue?